# gltf scene doesnt load using aframe in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, aframe, gltf

I am trying to load a scene.gltf that I have downloaded in my app.jsx (using react) however it does not load it and the background is white. I have create a model folder inside of public folder where inside I have put the scene.gltf and the scene.bin as well as the textures folder associate to it. I have also added the correct aframe script inside of the index.html file, but still for some reason it doesn't work...

Here is my app.jsx file:

```
/* eslint-disable */
import './App.css';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Typography, AppBar } from '@material-ui/core';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import RingLoader from 'react-spinners/RingLoader';
import { actionCreators as actionCreators_Orchestrator } from './components/actions_Orchestrator';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import { selectConnectionUrl } from './components/model_Orchestrator';
import LoadingEffect from 'react-loading-text';

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import SessionPage from './components/SessionPage';

import { Entity, Scene } from 'aframe-react';

import CreationSelection from './components/CreationSelection';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  appBar: {
    borderRadius: 15,
    margin: '30px 100px',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: '600px',
    border: '2px solid black',

    [theme.breakpoints.down('xs')]: {
      width: '90%'
    }
  },
  image: {
    marginLeft: '15px'
  },
  wrapper: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    width: '100%'
  },

  loading: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100vh',
    marginTop: '0px'
  },

  welcome: {
    color: 'cyan',
    textAlign: 'justify',
    fontStyle: 'italic'
  }
}));

const HomePage = ({ isConnected, loading, classes }) => {
  if (isConnected === false || loading === true) {
    return (
      <>
        <div className={classes.loading}>
          <RingLoader size={175} color="#36d7b7" loading={loading} />
          <h2 className="welcome"> Welcome! </h2>
          <h6 className="warm_up">Warming up the engine...</h6>
        </div>
        <LoadingEffect
          style={{
            default: [
              16,
              1,
              'white',
              2,
              0.5,
              'linear',
              () => alert('You are connected!')
            ]
          }}
        ></LoadingEffect>
      </>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <>
        <AppBar className={classes.appBar} position="static" color="inherit">
          <Typography variant="h2" align="center">
            TNO - SocialXR
          </Typography>
        </AppBar>
        <CreationSelection />
      </>
    );
  }
};

const BackgroundChanger = () => {
  const location = useLocation();

  const isUUIDPath = () => {
    const uuidRegex = /^[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\b-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\b-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\b-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\b-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}$/;
    const lastPathElement = location.pathname.split('/').pop();
    return uuidRegex.test(lastPathElement);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const originalImage = document.body.style.backgroundImage;

    if (isUUIDPath()) {
      document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/58/6e/51/586e51559dc40f48cd8ce65af9c1522f.gif)';
    }

    return () => {
      document.body.style.backgroundImage = originalImage;
    };
  }, [location]);

  return (
    <>
      {!isUUIDPath() && (
        <Scene embedded style={{ position: 'fixed', width: '100%', height: '100%' }}>
          <Entity gltf-model="/model/scene.gltf" />
          <Entity primitive="a-camera" position="0 0 5" />
        </Scene>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('hello');
    dispatch(actionCreators_Orchestrator.connect());
    dispatch(actionCreators_Orchestrator.toggleReconnect());
  }, [dispatch]);

  const isConnected = useSelector((state) => state.orchestrator.isConnected);

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setLoading(false);
    }, 4000);
  }, []);

  const remoteStreamsContainerId = 'remoteStreamsContainer';
  const containerStyle = { position: 'absolute', visibility: 'hidden' };

  return (
    <Router>
      <BackgroundChanger />
      <div className={classes.wrapper}>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<HomePage isConnected={isConnected} loading={loading} classes={classes} />} />
          <Route path="/:sessionId" element={<SessionPage />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
      <div id={remoteStreamsContainerId} style={containerStyle} />
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```